# Streaming API to refresh a Lightning page/App

Tags: lightning, streaming-api, pushtopic

I want a functionality which automatically refreshes a lightning page when there is a update in the object record details. I'm trying with Streaming API to achieve this. But the page is not refreshed whenever there is a update in the record. Please let me know what else I need to add to make it work.

Here are the details.

```
PushTopic:

PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'QueueUpdates1';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Name, AgentsAvailable__c FROM Queue_Status__c';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 36.0;
insert pushTopic;


Component:
 <lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi"/>
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

Controller:

  onInit: function(component, event, helper) {        
        var action = component.get("c.getQueues");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
                component.set("v.queues",response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

        const empApi = component.find('empApi');
        const channel = '/topic/QueueUpdates5';
        empApi.setDebugFlag(true);
        var handleError = function (error) {
            console.log('empApi error', error);
        };
        empApi.onError(handleError);

        empApi.subscribe(channel, -1, $A.getCallback(eventReceived => {
            console.log('Received event ', JSON.stringify(eventReceived));
             component.set("v.queueDetail",eventReceived.data.sobject);
        }));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was :  I was using my component in a standalone app , but empApi won't work with a standalone app . I added it to lightning experience (sales cloud) as per answers/comments mentioned in [Lightning Component empAPI in LightningApp](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256947/lightning-component-empapi-in-lightningapp) and it is working fine.