# How to Subscribe to platform Events on Community?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, platform-event

Trying to subscribe to a platform Event channel from community keep failing for me.

All is working fine from internal User on a Lightning Record Page but for some reason cannot subscribe to the Channel from Community.

Am I missing something ? anything needed to add here to make it work on community?

Using LWC but no luck using Aura as well. 
Got the Platform Event Setup "TestEvent__e".

```
import { LightningElement,track, api} from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, onError } from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class TestComp extends LightningElement {
 channelName = '/event/TestEvent__e';
 subscription = {};

 handleSubscribe() {
    // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
    const messageCallback = (response) => {
    console.log('Platform Event received : ', JSON.stringify(response,null,' '));     
    };

    // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
        // Response contains the subscription information on successful subscribe call
        console.log('Successfully subscribed to : ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        this.subscription = response; 
    });   
}
registerErrorListener() {
    // Invoke onError empApi method
    onError(error => {
        console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
        // Error contains the server-side error
    });
}}
```

HTML

```
<lightning-button variant="success" label="Subscribe" title="Subscribe"
    onclick={handleSubscribe} class="slds-m-left_x-small">
</lightning-button>
```

XML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>My Test Component</masterLabel>
    <description>Listen to EmpAPI</description>
     <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>`
```

Comment: in the Community's guest user Profile, did you enable read permissions for the Platform Event(s) in question? By default these are false.

Comment: yes have read and create permissions for the platform event object. any other permissions need to be enable for the community user?

Comment: I just found this post which clarify I guess that (currently?) this is not support in community - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243875/platform-event-lightningempapi?rq=1 - weird I imagined this is a good use case for platform Events.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do it.

Because Community Users don't have access to Push Topics ([idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnN8AAK)), [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33268/can-a-customer-community-user-access-pushtopics-for-streaming-api). And Platform Event, Data Change Event are built on Push Topics.

I have a similar use case where I need to use functionality in both Community and Internal, so I had to use different implementations based on the running environment.

**UPDATE**: actually you can [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289584/the-better-way-to-import-cometd-library-into-lwc/289588#289588)

Comment: That’s really surprising - Unlike push topics - you can give Read and Create permissions on a Plaform Event object to a community profile - but after various attempts I had to go to a different route here. It seems like currently not supported.

Comment: @ytiq how did you manage the "so I had to use different implementations based on the running environment"? What did you use here for Communities?

Comment: yey, I wanted to fix this answer)) I found out that actually you can) You can download cometd and subscribe to Platform Events using it check accepted answer here.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289584/the-better-way-to-import-cometd-library-into-lwc/289588#289588

Comment: What I meant is that I use events when component is used for communities and direct transactions when in Internal

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer(