# Platform Events not triggering for a profile but working for system admin

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, platform-event

My criteria is whenever a user updates a field to 'abc' a task is created with open status, once that field is updated to 'xyz' it set's the task status to completed, that will trigger the Process Builder which will trigger PE and I am displaying a popup using lightning EMPapi. This is working well for System Admin profile but not for a different profile. I have provided PE object permissions as well.

if I manually update the task to completed by logging in as that user, it is triggering PE but through actual process it is not initiating PE, and it's working for system admin profile with the same process.

My Process builder is firing but it's not triggering this empAPI for a particular profile, please let me know if I am missing any functionality or any other permissions that has to be added to this, thanks.

Comment: What other profile are you using as the subscriber of the platform event? Related post might help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/288520/18079

Comment: Thank You!! I had deleted the platform event and recreated that and it started working. Also had to redo the permissions.. I still don't know why that was causing the issue..